# Windows class name is not valid error - VS 2008/C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I created a form application with 1 button and 1 text box to see if i could recreate this error and i did. Upon compiling and trying to run with F5 i keep getting this error

```
     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.RegisterClass()
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.Create(String className, Int32 classStyle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
```

This is my main:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        **Application.Run(new Form1());**
    }
```

Error happens on the line in BOLD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be related to a bad version of comctl32.dll or similar DLL. Here is a discussion centered around TreeView:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e28e24cc-156c-433b-bc71-436384a3211d

Comment: Just posting a link is considered bad form. I'll Edit it a little, roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: For reference the comment in the link about the DLL: "Looks like the native InitCommonControlsEx() is failing.  It is called by the TreeView's CreateHandle() override but the framework doesn't check the return value.  Sloppy.  As to why it is failing: tough call.  Start by taking a good hard look at c:\windows\system32\comctl32.dll.  It is prone to be mangled by crummy install programs.  Mine is XP SP2, V5.82.2900.2180, 8/10/2004, 5am.  There's a backup copy in c:\windows\system32\dllcache.  The application manifest plays a role too.  And you may have some crumware allocating too many handles"

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this while working with an old project in Visual Studio 2005. After a bit of searching my memory was jogged enough to remember that this has something to do with the Visual Studio hosting process, and I fixed it by doing the following:
- go to Build->Clean Solution
- exit Visual Studio, open Windows Explorer, and go to the bin directory for the configuration you're working with (i.e., if you're in the Debug configuration, go to \bin\Debug).
- There should only be a few files left in there, most notably the hosting process executable (.vshost.exe). Delete this one, and to be safe any .config and .manifest files associated with the hosting process executable.
- Restart Visual Studio and build your solution again.

It may be possible to fix this by just deleting the hosting process executable without cleaning the solution. It may also be possible to delete the executable by going to the project properties, Debug settings, and unchecking the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox. The hosting process speeds up loading a Debug version, though, so re-enable it if you can.

(Edit) After revisiting this, I found another possible solution. Add the following line to the Main() function, before the call to Application.Run():

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```